# How do I update Windows Defender to use old definition files?

Tags: antivirus

I'm attempting to replicate a customer's issue locally. One of the differences is our Windows Defender definition file versions. The current version seems to be 1.269.694.0, and I'm looking for something in the 1.269.4xx.0 range.

It is easy to find information on how to [get the latest definitions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions). From that link, it seems I can manually clear out the definitions from the command prompt, then run an update file to update to a particular version. The problem I've hit is I can't find a list of non-current definitions files to update to, either in MSDN or via a search engine.

I'm not sure if there is, say, an admin setting for selecting an older version to use. It's also possible that I just failed to find the repository of old definitions files, if one exists.

So, how do I update Windows Defender to use old definition files?

Comment: Welcome! So you want to know where you can find X thing? I don't think this is on-topic for this site. Perhaps Google will have the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaJones I'm looking to configure antivirus software in a particular way for security-related testing. Since "security tools" are explicitly on topic, and there is an [tag:antivirus] tag, it seemed more appropriate here than on Superuser or another stack. Additionally, when I said "the internet at large" I meant searching using tools such as Google. Would it improve the question to make that more explicit?

Comment: `So, where can I find old Windows Defender definition files?` - you're asking where to find something, I don't deem that to be on topic.

Comment: @JoshuaJones If you can't be convinced otherwise, then I believe the appropriate action for you to take is to vote to close or flag for migration to a more appropriate stack.

Comment: @JoshuaJones I've mulled it over a bit, and realized I was posing something of an X-Y Problem question. I want to configure Defender in some way, but posed the question as the stumbling block I ran into attempting that. I've reworked the question such that the focus is now on what I want to do, not how I thought I should be doing it. Thanks for your feedback, and let me know if I can further improve the question.